# Does fish shell support alphabetic range expansion?

Tags: fish

In bash you can do this

```
echo {a..d}
```

and it will print

```
a b c d
```

How to do that in fish shell?

---

What I tried:

```
echo {a..d}
a..d

echo {a-d}
a-d

echo [a-d]
[a-d]

echo (seq 5)[a-d]
fish: Invalid index value
echo (seq 5)[a-d]
         ^

echo (seq 5)[a..d]
fish: Invalid index value
echo (seq 5)[a..d]
             ^
```

Does fish support alphabetic expansion at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does fish support alphabetic expansion at all?

No.

Use normal brace expansion - `{a,b,c,d}`.